# Compare and modify changes amongst GIS and MIS data

Tags: python, arcpy, sqlite

```
import arcpy
import sqlite3

# the column names
columnNames = ["ASSETNUM", "DESCRIPTIO", "INSERVICE", "ENGINEID"]

data = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(r'E:\mypathtoshp\Fire_Hydrants.shp', columnNames) as sCursor:
    for row in sCursor:
        data.append(row)

# create a connection to your sqlite database
conn = sqlite3.connect(r'E:\mypathtodb\MyDB.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# create a table within the database
cursor.execute(''' CREATE TABLE Hydrants_MIS(ASSETNUM text, DESCRIPTIO text, INSERVICE text, ENGINEID text)''')

# insert your new records
c = ['?' for c in range(len(columnNames))]
c = ','.join(c)
sql = 'INSERT INTO {} VALUES ({})'.format('Hydrants_MIS', c)
cursor.executemany(sql, data)
conn.commit()
```

I have the above code to create a table in SQLite and populate the data from shp file. The SQLite table serves as a MIS repository and the shp serves as GIS repo. My client will induce changes in GIS data.

I want to run a python code every 1 hour to compare the 'ASSETNUM' values from the MIS data(SQLITE) and GIS data(shp), checking whether any data has been modified/added/deleted. If there is any modifications, perform the following operations:

1. If there are any new rows in GIS data, pick the assetnum and update the fields in MIS data. Eg: There is a new asset added by the client in GIS data. I need the script to update this new data in the MIS table.
2. If some rows in GIS data were deleted, update the fields in MIS data. Eg: Some assets were not in use and were removed by the client in GIS data. I need the script to update this in the MIS table.
3. If there are modifications in the data, the updation should happen at MIS table as well.

So far, I have fetched the 'ASSETNUM' field values from both the sources to compare. I am stuck at structuring the conditional statements.

```
    import arcpy
     import sqlite3

    conn = sqlite3.connect(r'E:\mydbpath\MyDB.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    MIS_result = cur.execute("SELECT ASSETNUM FROM Hydrants_MIS")
    rows = MIS_result.fetchone("ASSETNUM")

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(r'E:\myshppath\Fire_Hydrants.shp', ["ASSETNUM"]) as sCursor:
    for row in sCursor:
        if <there are new assets >
            add the same records in sqlite table
        elif <some assets are deleted>
            delete the same records from sqlite table
         elif <change in field data of some assets>   
            update the same changes in sqlite table
        else
            no change
```

Comment: Can you make the actual question clearer? What have you tried so far?

Comment: what is the MIS initials you referring at?

Comment: MIS data is nothing but non-spatial data. It refers to Management Information system.

Comment: So far, I have fetched the 'ASSETNUM' field values from both the sources to compare. I am stuck at structuring the conditional statements.

Comment: how long does it take for the creation of the initial table from the GIS data? - if time/processing is negligible, would it be practical to simply drop the table and recreate it every hour?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using?  Why are you using shapefile for geometry when SQLite supports a geometry type?  Why aren't you using a more robust PostgreSQL solution?  Please **edit** the question.

Comment: @fluidmotion: This was exactly what I was thinking in the first place, but  unfortunately, it takes about 5-7 minutes to get executed. There are about 70lacs+  records.

Comment: @Vince: I am using 10.3. The architecture is the client's call. We can't mess with that. I asked the question because SQLite and python, both are new for me. The question remains the same and the scenario is very much explained. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: might be worth a shot to read both the sqlite table and the original feature class as dictionaries - then use [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165352/calculate-difference-in-keys-contained-in-two-python-dictionaries) to determine differences and update the table accordinglly?

Comment: Please **edit the question** to contain the information requested in comments.

Comment: The two times in my career when I wasn't able to convince my customer (the prime contractor) to alter a solution to use a reasonable architecture, the end customer issued a "stop work" and cancelled the contract for inadequate performance.

Answer (score 1):

You're working with Databases.
There is nothing to prevent you from adding new columns of a kind **date-added**  / **date-modified** with which they would be updated with an 'on insert' or 'on update' triggers. use time stamp data types for those columns.

That way you instantly can sort your entries on last update, or never been updated or whatever.

Comment: I understand I can use the time stamp to track the changes in the databases, but what I really want here is the updated data to be reflected in the other database. Eg: If i update a data for an asset in GIS db, the same should be reflected in the sqlite db. I can connect the dbs through the unique ASSETNUM field

Comment: @Amzy It's been decades since distinctions between GIS and MIS have been necessary. Treating databases as if they didn't have geometry capabilities is making your solution needlessly complex.